# Unable to share C drive for Docker Linux Container on Windows 10

Tags: docker, windows-10

A lot of people has been facing similar issues based on the several links that i checked, however, non of the solutions i have checked work for me:

1. Add Local account
   http://peterjohnlightfoot.com/docker-for-windows-on-hyper-v-fix-the-host-volume-sharing-issue/
2. Disable firewall
   https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1381
3. Weird characters on the passwords.
4. Tried to mount on D drive (external hard drive).

Could there be an apparent issue with my docker installation ? I also tried to uninstall, and re-install. I have tried to use both docker stable or edge version, same problem persisted.

On the top of that, i realized my docker is not giving me enough info to figure things out. The log that i have in my path %AppData%\Local\Docker shows only the following:

[image: Log file]

Is there any other place that i can check for my docker log ?

Added my docker-compose.yml file :[docker-compose.yml](http://txt.do/df0l1)

Added my docker file. [DockerFile](http://txt.do/df0lr)

Added my startup.sh file. [startup.sh](http://txt.do/df0lk)

Comment: How are you starting your container?

Comment: I believed i have not started my container. I am using Visual Studio 2017 with docker support. I ran my project in debug mode. It prompted me to enable volume sharing, i entered my credentials after i have selected the drive.

It ended with a "volume sharing is not enable..." error.

Comment: please share your Dockerfile

Comment: @techtrainer I added the related file in my post.

Comment: My problem is very similar to https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/690. but solutions mentioned in this link doesn't help.

Comment: did you tried 'docker-compose up'?

Comment: @techtrainer I did, it gave the same error at the end, says volume sharing is not enabled. 

I find it odd that i am unable to go into my mobyvirtualmachine via hyper-v manager.  It says session got disconnected -> clicked reconnect and failed. Maybe i can dig out more info from there.